# why CS GO Lags on i5 4th gen and 16gb ram?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I am having i5 4th gen and 16gb ram and 500 mb nvidia gforce 8400 gs card.
After trying to lower the graphics settings and reaching to the lowest setting my cs go lags in a game play.
I have set paging setting to system managed and approx 20 GB space is available in windows drive.
I have multicore rendering enabled and texture filtering mode is bilinear,aspect ratio normal 4:3, however resolution i have set to 640x480.

Can anyone please guide me in resolving this issue.

Comment: [Try asking here.](https://superuser.com) (Don't include the game, just the lag.)

Answer (score 0):

It's something that is VERY hard to answer since it can be a stupid amount of things from your install to a driver incompatibility.

So try to find out: is there anything that you can remove that when you don't have that on you do not lag? Are your drivers updated? Is there an effect in particular that your graphics card just sucks at?

Examples:

- Recently I had problems with Apex Legends. Just seemingly random spurts of lag. But I was running Apex Tracker in the background. Desactivating it stopped the lag.
- On one of my old computers, I had a shitty graphics cards. After a little while, I realised that any dynamic shadows would kill my performance. So every game, I would need to go to graphics options and put shadows to none or the lowest setting. Everything else could stay medium/high, but if there was shadows, blam. lag.

For your problem in particular, I would go for a driver problem. You have a setup that if I read right, you should blow any requirements of CSGO out of the water. So something is misfiring.

But you might be in luck: CSGO has a huge community and tools to see exactly how your computer is trying to run it so search around, you might find a tool that can search and benchmark your PC to find what problems it encounters.

Comment: I have tried updating drivers, then i tried running on the most lower settings, killing almost unnecessary processes from background, tried different forums and tools to check if pc can run cs go on my configuration or not, And finally putting the question here.

Comment: Yeah there definitively something that is misfiring on your PC. But as I said there's a huge community around CSGO that wants shit do run buttery smooth so there is probably a bugfinding tool somewhere to help. I'm at work rn so I can't help you look, but it must exist somewhere.

Comment: Probably just opening the console of CSGO in a match might give you errors that you can use to debug. I dont remember exactly how to open it, check the keyboard controls settings, but I think its the ~ key. Then go run around in a random match and if something goes wrong it should put messages in there.